# Does pg (node-postgres) automatically sanitize data

Tags: node.js, pg, node-postgres

I am using `node-postgres` for a production application and I am wondering if there is anything I should be concerned about? Is the data sanitized automatically by `node-postgres`?

I couldn't find anything about it on the github page: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how you execute your queries:

Formatting via `Prepared Statements` is executed by the server, which in turn sanitizes your query from any SQL injection. But it has other restrictions, like you cannot execute more than one query at a time, and you cannot provide sanitizied entity names when needed.

Client-side query formatting, like the one implemented by [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), sanitizes values, plus offers flexibility in formatting entity names and multiple queries.

Comment: Stupid question - can a formatted string query be considered a prepared statement if passed to `.query`? where are docs on this?

Comment: or would it have to be this syntax?
```var queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(password_hash, email) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id'
client.query(queryText, ['841l14yah', 'test@te.st'```

Comment: got that here https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ

Comment: @VincentBuscarello A query is executed as [Prepared Statement](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/PreparedStatement.html) when it is passed into query method as `{name, text, values}`.

Answer (score 35):

> Absolutely! The parameterized query support in node-postgres is first class. All escaping is done by the postgresql server ensuring proper behavior across dialects, encodings, etc... For example, this will not inject sql:
>
> ```
> client.query("INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES($1)", ["'; DROP TABLE user;"], function (err, result) {
>   // ...
> });
> ```

This is from their [documentation](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ).

Answer (score 20):

It basically depends on how you execute your queries as @vitaly-t described

Suppose you will define query in a string and execute as follows:

```
var query = `SELECT * FROM table where username='${username}' and password='${password}`;
        
pool.query(query, (error, results) => {
});
```

This case if i would pass *username*=**' 'or 1=1; --** and *password*=**' 'or 1=1; --**

Then it will return all records from the table (means SQL injection works)

**But** if I would execute the following query

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM table where username=$1 and password=$2', [username, password], (error, results) => {
});
```

Then SQL injection will never work because pg will sanitize the data.

So it's depends on how you execute the queries.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `query =  "SELECT * FROM table where username='${username}' and password='${password}'"` ?

PS: could not add the `