# Querying Postgres with multiple parameters Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm just starting with Node.js to build a `Node.js` server with `Postgres` db, I have in place a few routes and methods for CRUD operations :

```
router.get('/products', productController.listAllProducts);
```

```
exports.listAllProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC');
  if (response.rowCount > 0) {
    res.status(200).send(response.rows);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({
      message: "No products found"
    });
  }
};
```

and in Postman the url `localhost:3000/api/products` works just fine.
Now I'm trying to include 3 parameters in the query `city`, `region` and `country`

```
router.get('/products', productController.findCityProducts); // correct route??
```

```
exports.findCityProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const city = req.query.city;
  const region = req.query.region;
  const country = req.query.country;
  const response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3', [city,region,country]);
  if (response.rowCount > 0) {
    res.status(200).send(response.rows);
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({
      message: 'Product not found'
    });
  }
};
```

and in Postman I add the 3 parameters so the url is `localhost:3000/api/products?city=Bologna&region=Emilia-Romagna&country=Italy` but the results are the same as for the `listAllProducts` method.. and there is no record that satisfies the query..so I guessed the `'/products' route can't have more than one method assigned..and is calling` listAllProducts`..I commented it out and indeed now is calling` findCityProduct`.

How would I to enable both the `listAllProducts` and `findCityProduct` queries?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, you can't have two routes with the same path and HTTP method (GET /products) defined using different controller functions (listAllProducts, findCityProducts).

One simple approach you could take here is to adapt your controller function to behave differently depending on the existence of parameters in the URL.

**Also, it is worth noting that you should be sanitizing any external input before using them in SQL queries to avoid injections.**

```
router.get('/products', productController.listProducts);


exports.listProducts = async (req, res) => {

  const { city, region, country } = req.query
  let response

  if (city && region && country) {
    response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE city = $1 AND region = $2 AND country = $3', [city,region,country]);
  } else {
    response = await db.query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY productName ASC'); 
  }

  if (response.rowCount > 0) {
     res.status(200).send(response.rows);
  } else {
     res.status(404).send({ message: "No products found" });
  }
};
```

Comment: Grat thanks, glad to see I almost got it yesterday. I was trying a check like `if (req.query.city != null)` and then getting the values like `const city = req.query.city` and so on.. So I see I can  declare the 3 variables without specifying their value taken from a specific query parameter.

Comment: I'm very new to security, but all data will be encrypted/decripted within the cloud functions that are calling the Node API, also the writing/reading to the db are user/password protected as `DATABASE_URL=postgres://{db_username}:{db_password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}`stored in a `.env` file. What else are cautious steps to take in order to get security level up?

Comment: You must validate and sanitize the inputs that come via URL in this case. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455585/does-pg-node-postgres-automatically-sanitize-data

Comment: Hi again, in the code from your example, you're using a `Parameterized query` right? If so SQLI shouldn't work as they state : `Absolutely! The parameterized query support in node-postgres is first class. All escaping is done by the postgresql server ensuring proper behaviour across dialects, encodings, etc...` Sorry to bother again but' I'm getting a little confused about normal queries ( allowing SQLI ) `Prepared statements` ( which needs `pg-promise`) and  `Parameterized queries` (done in `node-postgres` that does the input sanitizing automatically if I got it right..)